# docusign rest api - preview the envelope

Tags: docusignapi

I am using rest api for docusign integration.
I am creating the envelope with multiple templates ( using composite template)and trying to preview it in readonly mode.
In my case, the the work flow goes like this... Rep ( Creates envelope and previews it in readonly mode). If everything looks good in preview, then click sent button in my App UI, which will actually sent the envelope to 3 remote recipients ( signer 1, signer2, signer3 -these are actual signers).
I am able to create and sent but not able to preview the envelope in read only mode.
1) Tried downloading the document as byte[].. but the prefill field data is missing
2) Tried by adding a previewer role to the templates and then make him as embedded user. Then created recipients view.. this again is missing the prefill data.
How to preview a created envelope in non editable mode with prefill field data?

Answer (score 1):

Enable "Display SecureField initial value to all recipients" in Preferences --> Features and then the downloaded document (post send) should have all the tab data filled in. However, this will also show tab data to other recipients, Signer 1 will see tab data prefilled for Signer 3 during signing.

Comment: Thank you... my issue is the rep who created the envelope need to preview the documents with prefill data.

Comment: /documents/combined?watermark=true&&show_changes=true

Answer (score 0):

Hello All I am able to download the documents from envelope that is in draft ..created status.
1) Do as Rickey told in above answer and then I used below url condiftions.

/documents/combined?watermark=true&&show_changes=true